# Integral: $I = \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \frac{\ln^3(\cos x) + \ln^2(\cos x)\tan x - \ln(\cos x)\cot^2 x}{\sin^3 x}\,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals

I need some help in evaluating $I$, which is the integral:

$$I = \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \frac{\ln^3(\cos x) + \ln^2(\cos x)\tan x - \ln(\cos x)\cot^2 x}{\sin^3 x}\,dx$$

**Clarifications:**

- For better readability, the expression $\ln^3(\cos x)$ represents $(\ln(\cos x))^3$.
- The term $\ln^2(\cos x)\tan x$ denotes $(\ln(\cos x))^2 \times \tan x$.
- If any other interpretations are possible, please advise.

**First Steps:**

\begin{align*}
I &= \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \frac{\ln^3(\cos x) + \ln^2(\cos x)\tan x - \ln(\cos x)\cot^2 x}{\sin^3 x} \, dx \\
&= \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \frac{\ln^3(\cos x) + \ln^2(\cos x)\tan x - \ln(\cos x)\frac{\cos^2 x}{\sin^2 x}}{\sin^3 x} \, dx \\
&= \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \frac{\ln^3(\cos x) + \ln^2(\cos x)\tan x - \ln(\cos x)\csc^2 x}{\sin x} \, dx
\end{align*}
$$ = \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \frac{\ln^3(\cos x) + \ln^2(\cos x)\tan x - \ln(\cos x)\cot(x)\csc(x)}{\sin x} \, dx$$

Comment: Is $~\ln^2(\cos x)\tan x~$ intended to represent $~\left[ ~\ln(\cos x)~\right]^2 \times \tan x,~$ or is it intended to represent something else?

Comment: Your posting is missing several details.
Please see [this article on MathSE protocol](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236).

Comment: Welcome to MSE. A reasonable first step might be to replace all those trigonometric expressions with simpler algebraic ones. At the very least, you should include *something* that you tried.

Comment: wolfram says it is not convergent. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%5Cint_0%5E%7Bpi%2F4%7D+%28+log%28cos%28x%29%29%5E3+%2B+log%28cos%28x%29%29%5E2+tan%28x%29+-+log%28cos%28x%29%29+cot%28x%29%5E2+%29%2Fsin%5E3%28x%29+dx+

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, look at what happens around $x=0$.

Around this value, a Taylor series of the integrand gives
$$\text{integrand} =\frac{1}{2 x^3}-\frac{13 x}{240}+O\left(x^2\right)$$ Do you see the problem ?

For the antiderivatives, let $x=\cos^{-1}(t)$ to face
$$-\int\frac{\log ^3(t)}{\left(1-t^2\right)^2}\,dt-\int\frac{\log ^2(t)}{t
   \left(1-t^2\right)^{3/2}}\,dt+\int\frac{t^2 \log
   (t)}{\left(1-t^2\right)^3}\,dt$$ which has an explicit solution (in particular in terms of generalized hypergeometric functions and polylogarithms).